# Android: can't use android.nfc.NfcSecureElement?

Tags: android, nfc

I wanted to use `android.nfc.NfcSecureElement` but I kept getting

`The import android.nfc.NfcSecureElement cannot be resolved`

Although I can use `android.nfc.NfcAdapter` with no problem

Do I need to update something or am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: check weather  NfcSecureElement class is public

Comment: It is `public final class NfcSecureElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.nfc.NfcSecureElement` had never been part of the official Android API and was removed from AOSP more than 3 years ago (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/367f41f8f61126c2ab34a34cc676756a9fc23ac2)). Hence, it's simply not available on any current Android platform.

More precisely, it's only available on Android 2.3.3 and even then it's hidden from the SDK.

Comment: exactly I found out it is not a part of the public android SDK, thank you

Answer (score 1):

NfcSecureElement is not included on android.jar that used in your project.

Comment: I'm targeting my project to `API 19`, i.e. `Android 4.4.2`

Comment: If you're using eclipse, you can check : Go to your project > Android 4.4.2 > android.jar
Expand android.jar, then expand android.nfc folder
You cannot see NfcSecureElement.java there
I'm also using android 4.4.2

Comment: It does not exist, but I don't know why

Comment: I'm not sure about the reason. But you can try to use another class that have similar functionality with this class. You can check this [link](https://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/)

Comment: I found a post about this saying this whole thing is not a part of the public SDK, thank you anyway